# Java looping issue reading out incorrectly

Tags: java

Ok, so I am trying to get this output:
Die 0: 6 letters
Die 1: 6 letters
etc:

and right now its printing out Die 0: then the whole read file of letters

This is the class that is doing the looping and I posted the other methods what there doing from a different java package.

```
public void populateDice()
{

    //Loop through the 16 dice times
    for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_DICE; row++){

    //Create an instance of class Die using the no-argument constructor
        //Die die = new Die();

    //Loop through the 6 sides of the die:
        for (int col= 0; col < NUMBER_OF_SIDES; col++)
        {

            Die die = new Die();
    //Add each of the 6 letters to the die ArrayList representing 
    //the die letters by calling method addLetter in class Die 
           die.addLetter(diceData.get(col).toString());

    //Display the letters of each die by calling method displayAllLetters() in class Die on a separate row
           System.out.println("Die " + row + ":");
           die.displayAllLetters();

    }


    }
   }


public void displayAllLetters()       
{

    try{

    //Loop through all sides of the die and display the data
    for(int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_SIDES; x++)
    {
        System.out.println(diceStore.get(x));
    }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.printf("ERROR %s", ex.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: It's very hard to follow what's where. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (It's particularly unclear why you have a variable of class `Class` named `Die`, by the way...)

Comment: I cleaned it up for you

Comment: That's still not a short but complete program. It starts with a method declaration, for one thing...

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is structured, the first for-loop is die0. Once you get to the inner for-loop you create your new Die, add 1 letter, then tell it to print all of the letters.

I think what you're wanting is to initialize all the the sides then print the letters, so you would have displayAllLetters() outside of the inner for-loop.

```
 //Loop through the 16 dice times
for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_DICE; row++)
{

    //Create an instance of class Die using the no-argument constructor
    Die die = new Die();

    //Loop through the 6 sides of the die:
    for (int col= 0; col < NUMBER_OF_SIDES; col++)
    {

        //Die die = new Die(); --- remove this and do it in the above loop ^
        //Add each of the 6 letters to the die ArrayList representing 
        //the die letters by calling method addLetter in class Die 
        die.addLetter(diceData.get(col).toString());

        //Display the letters of each die by calling method    displayAllLetters() in class Die on a separate row
       //System.out.println("Die " + row + ":"); -----move this out of the for-loop
       //die.displayAllLetters(); ----- move this out of the for-loop

    }
    System.out.println("Die " + row + ":");
    die.displayAllLetters();

}
```